# Spring Boot RabbitMQ Pub/Sub Model with Queue creation/subscriptions at runtime and container scaling

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-websocket

I have a Spring Boot application with a basic WebSocketConfigurer.  At a high level, for each established connection, I want that websocket session to "subscribe" to a "channel" dedicated to that session.  The consumer would simply take any message that comes in on the subscription and send it along on the web socket session.

Here are some constraints: when a websocket connection is created, it is associated with a "conversation id" during the handshake (passed in as a query parameter).  That websocket must receive messages only associated with that conversation id, and not others.  At the same time, I have a rest endpoint that allows the backend to make an HTTP POST to a path URL associate with that conversation id (e.g. `/conversations/12345`).  I need to be able to take those inbound messages and route them to the correct websocket session.

It's also important to note that there will be multiple instances of this service running - and I want to avoid messages being picked up by an instance that does not have the originating websocket session.

I'm putting "subscribe", "subscription", "channel" in quotes because they represent an high level Pub/Sub concept that is not implementation specific.

I landed on RabbitMQ as my Pub/Sub model.  Given that we're working with Rabbit, the "channel" would exist as a Queue in Rabbit.  Looking at the countless examples and documents out there- it mainly covers a scenario with a static, predetermined set of queues.  In this case one can simply declare a RabbitListener annotated method with code to handle messages on the queue specified in the anno.

In this case, I must create these subscriptions at runtime.  I know the AmqpAdmin allows one to declare queues and bindings at runtime.  As far as connecting to the queue, there seems to be the concept of rabbit "endpoints" and "listener container".

In most examples, the "endpoints" are hidden under the hood, an we simply create a DirectMessageListenerContainer (or SimpleMessageListenerContainer), use the injected ConnectionFactory and pass it into setConnectionFactory, then define a MessageListener and set that on the container.

Here's where I run into my first issue.  A MessageListenerContainer can only have one MessageListener instance associated it.  I can create queues with the AmqpAdmin, and add those queue references to the container using addQueues(), but then all messages on either of the added queues would go to the same MessageListener.

I was hoping to have one MessageLisener instance that is interested in one queue with a reference to one WebSocketSession.  The handle method would simple push messages coming in on the queue to that WebSocket.  However, if I can only have one MessageListener, I'm left with creating some kind of ConcurrentHashMap on the MessageListener so I can look up the correct WebSocketSession by queue name (you can get the queue name from the inbound Message) in order to push to the right WebSocketSession.

My initial crack at this using just a single Listener had something like this:

An implementation of `WebSocketConfigurer` that would take the `conversationId` param of the inbound handshake and save it as an attribute

```
        @Override
        public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
            String conversationId = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest().getParameter("conversationId");
            
            attributes.put("conversationId", conversationId);
            return true;
        }
```

For every connection established, create a queue named after the websocket session id, and create a binding to that queue using the `conversationId`.  This also meant that I had to keep track of the open websocket session and associated sessionId in a ConcurrentHashMap (inside of `WebSocketSessionStore`).  I also kept track of the created queue and binding for the sake of cleanup.:

```
        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
            String conversationId = session.getAttributes().get("conversationId").toString();
            sessionStore.sessions().put(session.getId(), session);

            Queue q = new Queue(session.getId());
            //Autowired AmqpAdmin 
            admin.declareQueue(q);
            //Autowired DMLC
            container.addQueues(q);
            sessionStore.queues().put(session.getId(), q);

            //Autowired DirectExchange
            Binding b = BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(exchange).with("conversation." + conversationId);
            admin.declareBinding(b);
            sessionStore.bindings().put(session.getId(), b);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
            Binding b = sessionStore.bindings().remove(session.getId());
            admin.removeBinding(b);

            Queue q = sessionStore.queues().remove(session.getId());
            container.removeQueues(q);
            admin.deleteQueue(q.getName());

            sessionStore.sessions().remove(session.getId());
        }
```

My DMLC would simple contain a `MessageListener` that would use the queue name to look up the correct WebSocketSession and push the message.

```
@Bean
public DirectMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, WebSocketSessionStore sessionStore) {
    DirectMessageListenerContainer container = new DirectMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            WebSocketSession ws = sessionStore.sessions().get(message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue());
            try {
                ws.sendMessage(new TextMessage(message.getBody()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        
    });
    return container;
}
```

My next thought was to then create a new MessageListenerContainer along with a new MessageListener for every new WebSocketSession that connects.  This would allow me to create a new MessageListener instance that holds a reference to the WebSocketSession and is dedicated to the one Queue get is created for the WebSocket.  But now this means creating many containers which I'm not sure is a good practice.  How many containers can be created?  Are they expensive?

I haven't looked much into what a RabbitListenerEndpoint is, and how it relates to containers.  It seems like something I shouldn't be interacting with directly, as they appear to be managed by the containers or something.  But perhaps I am incorrect in that assumption.

Ultimately I want to have a dedicated "subscription" to a "channel" (queue?) for each websocket that comes in.  I'm just stuck working out the correct implementation details that uses RabbitMQ properly.

In anticipation of anyone suggesting STOMP: I am looking into using Spring Stomp message broker with rabbit as a possible alternative.  But that would be separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RabbitListenerEndpoint` is simply a vehicle used by the infrastructure to create a message listener container and adapter for a `@RabbitListener` method.

You can make the bean a prototype bean (instead of the default singleton), then each one retrieved from the application context gets its own listener container.

However, you are correct in that creating many containers would not be good practice. So routing within a single listener would probably be the best approach for this scenario. However, you would not need a queue for each subsriber (unless the subscriptions must be durable, and able to get messages sent while the subscriber is disconnected).

Comment: a response from the legend himself!  I was hoping to hear from you Gary.  I'm working on editing the question.  The reason why I was thinking multiple queues was because I only want certain messages to go to certain web socket sessions.  I suppose I could jam everything in the same queue and use something in the payload to determine which session to route to, but I figured I would give each session its own queue.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code that uses a single container.  It sounds like I can't make use of the prototype scoped `@RabbitListener`.  Perhaps I can keep it singleton and use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` to retrieve the container as needed.  But I just followed the spring tutorial which had it declared as a `@Bean`.

Comment: Even with separate queues, you would have to look at the `consumerQueue` message property to decide where to send it, so I don't see much difference, and it would avoid the overhead of adding and removing queues at runtime.

Comment: Makes sense - my concern was with scaling and volume.  How much traffic can a single queue handle?  Also as additional instances of the service spin up, I would want to avoid messages being delivered to instances that don't have the originating websocket.